# Some CSS styles not being applied when editing a pre-made wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to mess around with a pre-purchased wordpress theme.

I am trying to change the visit, active, hover and active states of links in the navigation but the changes don't show up because I think it's being overriden with the default stylesheet.

How do you make sure that when you apply css, it won't be overridden from the default stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to enqueue (with WordPress hook)  your custom style in footer and try to check. So your CSS would apply in last and you can override default CSS of theme. Please let me know if you have any queries for same.

Comment: function custom_add_footer_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css-id', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
};
add_action( 'get_footer', 'custom_add_footer_styles' );